# How to Join Intersected Points by Location

Tags: qgis

I extracted nodes from polygon parcel layer by Geometry Tools > Extract Nodes. However there are many crossed unnecessary points with same location after extracted nodes. There is a topic like this:  [Join attributes by location](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43858/join-attributes-by-location)

[image]

Is there any way to simplify unnecessary points?

Comment: Do you need the attributes of each overlapped point? Otherwise, you could use the **Delete duplicate geometries** to remove all points at the same location (this will leave you with the last point in your attribute table).

Comment: The answer posted by @gcarrillo [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/how-to-merge-same-long-lat-points-with-different-data-into-a-unique-one) is a good method if you need the individual attributes.

Comment: Thanks. I will try those methods. Attribute info is not important, just x,y is important for this.

Comment: I solved this problem via SAGA's Remove Duplicated Points.

Comment: Awesome! You should post your solution as an **answer** to close this question off :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem via SAGA's Remove Duplicated Points.